# How to ensure the methods are not inlined by the java compiler?

Tags: java, eclipse

For testing purposes I need to be sure that certain methods are not inlined when the respective code is compiled to produce the .class files.

How do I do it in Eclipse?

**EDIT**

For those who really need to know **why**, before they tell **how**, here is the explanation - I am testing a code, which examines and manipulates JVM byte code. This is why I want sometimes to avoid method inlining.

Comment: How does this affect testing.  Code is only ever inlined when it makes no functional difference. The only difference you will see will be performance.  For performance testing you want your code to be processed exactly as it will be for production, otherwise the test is worthless.

Comment: When you receive questions of "why" in response to a "how"l; it usually infers "we don't know, but if you give us a little more background we may still be able to help".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java methods are never inlined when producing the .class files (only by an optimizing JVM at run time), so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: BTW, do you have a reference? Like Java spec or something?

Comment: @mark: I feel like I read it somewhere in the JLS or JVM spec recently, but searching again I can't find it. I've the vague idea that not only are the methods guaranteed to be present in the class file, <s>they even have to be in the same order as they were in the source</s> -- *nope, that's initializer blocks*. They have to be present at least for [Class.getDeclaredMethods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29) to work.

Comment: @mark: I just realized maybe that wasn't what you meant, if you're interested in the bytecode of the methods that could get other methods inlined into them, rather than the bytecode of the inlined methods themselves. I don't think there's a formal guarantee about that. It seems like a compiler could rightly inline things if it leaves the uninlined code present. But the standard javac, for one, does not inline methods, even if they're `private static final`. It's a raw and lazy conversion of the source.

Answer (score 4):

You don't; you have very little control over how the compiler and JIT optimize bytecode.

It's not clear to me why you'd want to do this, though.

Note that various JVM implementations may allow tweaking, e.q., `-XX:MaxInlineSize=` in HotSpot might be set to an impossibly-low number meaning no methods would be inlined. There may be an equivalent option in the Eclipse compiler, but I'd be wary.

Comment: I am not talking about JIT, which compiles Java byte code into the machine code.

Comment: @mark I actually know what JIT compilation is. My statement still stands: you have very little control over how the compiler and JIT optimize bytecode, and I know of no reliable, cross-compiler way of controlling initial bytecode output, or any subsequent optimization.

Comment: Do you want to say that the answer provided by Boann (which I have marked) is wrong?

Comment: @mark I won't say it's wrong, because I don't know. Proving a negative is really difficult, and I don't have the time to try.

Comment: @mark I'd also add that you can't control what bytecode is emitted, across compiler vendors and versions. Without knowing what specific markers and manipulations you're doing, it's difficult to be more helpful.

Comment: @Dave Boan's statement is correct. The JLS guarantees that you can get a stack trace that corresponds to the source code, which means if you inline code you have to store additional information (which is what the JIT does) to generate it - problematic for class files. Furthermore inlining would only be legal in rather specific cases since we may only recompile certain parts of the program or add subclasses.. In practice javac and co won't ever inline methods for those reasons - iirc that's even spelled out in the JLS at some point.

Comment: @Voo Could be. Still doesn't sound like "can't" or "will never" to me, and w/o knowing what the OP is specifically trying to do, *I* would be uncomfortable guaranteeing anything across every `javac` implementation, which is why I don't.

Comment: I've got to agree with dave newton on this one. This is not something which was ever in the functional speck of java.  Nor is it likely to turn up in a maual.  There's no point getting upset when people ask you why you need this, its such an odd request that the only answer you're likely to get is "we don't know, sun / oracle never told us, we've never had a reason to ask.".  To java developers, what goes on between source code and runtime is a black box.  It is fact VERY implementation specific and not well documented by ANY implementation.

Comment: @Dave Yes in theory the compiler may be able to inline functions that don't inspect the stack (no exceptions) and are final and it is guaranteed the code is in the same compilation unit, etc. (which doesn't leave much possibilities really). So for one it certainly can't do it for non-final non-static protected/public methods.

Comment: It's not a great idea to start determining what implementations do on the theory of what they could do.  What you tend to find is that compilers COULD do a lot more than they actually do.  I see no reason for a method not inspecting the stack while inlined, this is happening at compile time, so its stack frame references can be adjusted.  There is nothing to stop the compiler inlining a method and keeping a copy in the .class file that is not inlined.  This pretty much throws the option open to anything that is not final.

Comment: @couling Except that the class file structure is specified and doesn't provide the possibility to store the information you want it to (i.e. "This method is inlined, assume this stack frame" - and that's ignoring recursion). The JIT is much freer in that regard (and does these things) as its data structures aren't documented..

Comment: I'm not quite understanding you there... In theory inlining doesn't have to be achieved by simply copying the byte code of the inlined method.  When the method is inlined, what is to stop it's byte code being changed (at worst completely re-compiled from source) to fit as if it had always been code in the method it was inlined into?

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to Java inlining functions, you are entirely at the whim of the compiler. You have no say in it whatsoever.

There are some various metrics that it uses to determine if something should be inlined. I believe one of these is the number of bytecode instructions in the method. So if you had a method like this:

```
void foo() {
    if(SOME_GLOBAL_BOOLEAN_THATS_ALWAYS_FALSE) {
        // lots of statements here
    }
    // code here
}
```

You might be able to reduce the chance of it inlining on you, provided you were clever enough in your if statement to make sure it wasn't going to optimize it out on you.

Comment: Actually the modern JIT compiler may detect that there is no code setting the global to true and will actually compile out that code.  If any class is later loaded to change that value java can (quite cleverly) remove the optimization.  Got to love java 6.

Comment: @couling exactly; that's the "provided you were clever enough" part.